# Hitting a leq(m) spec

Tags: cinema

Doing sound design for materials that need to hit an 82 leq(m) spec which is the TASA standard for cinema ads. But all I have is an LUFS meter. Any ballpark range I can mix it to, at least to pass the QC? Never mind being a tad soft, we just need to hit the spec.

I understand that there are complications because these are different metering standards. If there was any way to get my hands on a dolby unit or derivative plugins, or rent a dub stage, I would. I have exhausted other options, but there are limitations and considerations with this specific project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

All of the cinema spot mixes I've done over the last couple years require the mix to be at broadcast levels.  It used be that we delivered leg(m) mixes but at least for NCM they now ask for a broadcast -24 lufs mix.

Who are you delivering the mix to?  Are you actually doing the mix or just sound design?

Comment: I mixed it to a broadcast -24 LUFS standard. But their spec sheet does mention an 82 leq(m) spec. 

I don't know where the mix will end up with. They just want the mats to be "in the bag" when they decide to run it. They know I can't meter the leq spec, and I still advised them to bring it to someone or a dub stage that can.

In the meantime, I'm trying to figure out at least if anyone has a workaround or at least from experience figured out a "safe" figure to mix around on.

Comment: I think the Waves WLM meter (as well as the dolby MM2) will measure LEQ(m).  If you have Waves plugs already maybe see if the demo will work to get you through this one spot.  If you think you might have more of these type of mixes coming up, $400 is pretty reasonable I think.

Comment: unfortunately there isn't a way to really get around the spec without the proper meters.  Sometimes the specs can be outdated if nobody is there to update them.  If it were myself I would ask what company the spot is going to and then check their site for specs or call, updates might have been done since the agency received their spec sheet.  Some agencies only do a cinema spot every couple years.  I'm not sure your location but it seems like here in the US NCM is the dominant company in this field.

Comment: Thanks for the info and tips. Downloading the WLM demo. Cheers :)